# launchImageLibrary function on react-native-image-picker not launching on Android SDK 30

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am facing a problem when calling `launchImageLibrary` on React Native app.

`react-native-image-picker` version 4.0.6 - latest
Android compileSdkVersion = 30, targetSdkVersion = 30

It worked well on SDK version 29 and `react-native-image-picker` 3.4, but Playstore requirement was updated to 30. So, I updated the SDK version and had "Activity error".
So, I thought it is react-native-image-picker version issue, I updated it to 4.0.6

But still, I am having `selectionLimit` error. Could anyone help me to fix this error?
[`selectionLimit` error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG7W5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `selectionLimit` option when calling launchImageLibrary function.

Try this.

```
launchImageLibrary({
    selectionLimit: 0
  }, response => {
     
  }
)
```

Comment: If it's working, you can set this answer as accepted by clicking on the icon which is below the "0" on the left of answer